# AngularJs uigrid custom footer:How to sum the value of the given column(int type) and showing it in the grid footer

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using ui-grid to show the data.In the grid there are two columns :

1)Name

2)Salary

Let's say there are 100 rows in my grid.I am using custom footer in my grid

**gridFooterTemplate: 'total hours/IC charge:{{grid.appScope.ttlHrs}}'**

**Here is the code :**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', '$q',     function ($scope, $http, $interval, $q) {
$scope.ttlHrs=10;
$scope.gridOptions = {
columnDefs: [
  { name: 'name' },
  { name: 'salary' }
],
gridFooterTemplate: '<div style="background-color:#6C87A0;color:white">total salary:{{grid.appScope.ttlSal}}</div>',
onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ){
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

  // interval of zero just to allow the directive to have initialized
  $interval( function() {
    gridApi.core.addToGridMenu( gridApi.grid, [{ title: 'Dynamic item', order: 100}]);
  }, 0, 1);

  gridApi.core.on.columnVisibilityChanged( $scope, function( changedColumn ){
    $scope.columnChanged = { name: changedColumn.colDef.name, visible: changedColumn.colDef.visible };
  });
}
};

$http.get('some url')
.success(function(data) {
  $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
 });
}]);
```

Here I am showing 10 in footer for the sum of salary.Can any one tell me how we can sum the salary of all rows and the show here

After spending some time on research I am able to do this in this way :

```
$.each($scope.gridData, function (index, value) {
                 $scope.ttlHrs += parseInt($scope.gridData[index].Salary, 10);

             });
```

This solution is working for me.

Can anyone tell me another better way for doing this.

Comment: Where are you calculating the sum of salaries ?

Comment: That is what  I want to know how to sum the salary and update the uigrid footer.

Comment: Here for understanding I have used the scope variable "ttlHrs" static value.How to update this variable at run time?

Comment: If you are getting the data using $http.get, then you can try to find the sum in the .success and assign to a vairable inside that like 
$scope.total = your value; and try total in the footer

Comment: Yes I am doing the same now.Thanks for the solution.Is there any another way in angular for doing this.As you can see the code I am using.Any another optimized solution?

Comment: If you are getting the data in $http.get, then you will be able to find the sum in .success only, so how can you do it at some other place.